# Projections $P$ and $Q$ such that $I-(P+Q)$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $P,Q$ be endomorphisms of a finite dimensional linear space, such that $P^2 = P$ and $Q^2 = Q$. If $I-(P+Q)$ is invertible, then $P$ and $Q$ has the same rank.

The solution is that $rk(P) = rk(P(I-P-Q)) = rk(-PQ) = rk((I-Q-P)Q) = rk(Q)$. However, I am wondering if it is possible to have two projections $P$ and $Q$ such that $I-(P+Q)$ is invertible? Can someone please give me an example?

Comment: If $P = Q$, then $I - 2P = (1-P) - P$ is the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-grading on your ambient vector space $V$ with eigenvalue $+1$ on $(1-P)V$ and eigenvalue $-1$ on $PV$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A low-tech example which can be adapted to any dimension. Take 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P=\begin{bmatrix}
1&a&b\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\ c&1&d\\ 0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
$I -(P+Q)$ has determinant $-ac$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a matrix $P$ satisfies $P^2=P$ if and only if $(2P-I)^2=I$.

Call $R=2P-I$, $S=2Q-I$. Then $I-(P+Q) = \dots = \frac{1}{2}(R+S)$.

So my attempt is to find two matrices such that $R^2=S^2=I$ and $R+S$ is invertible.

For example I found

$$
R= \left(
\begin{matrix}
2 & \sqrt{3} \\
- \sqrt{3}& -2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
$$
S=\left(
\begin{matrix}
2 & -\sqrt{3} \\
 \sqrt{3}& -2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Getting

$$
P=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\begin{matrix}
3 & -\sqrt{3}+1 \\
 \sqrt{3}+1& -1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
$$
Q=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\begin{matrix}
3 & \sqrt{3}+1 \\
 -\sqrt{3}+1& -1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$